# Are there differences between Web Novel, Light Novel and Manga of Mushoku Tensei?

Tags: mushoku-tensei

I'm currently reading manga and I was thinking to switch to LN or WN so I'm wonder to what I should read WN or LN.

I'm current in chapter 15 in manga.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the manga follows the same path as the web novel with much skipped content. I don't know about the light novel but I read somewhere that there are some differences. And according to Wikipedia ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushoku_Tensei#Volume_list)), there exists a whole volume between WN volumes 6 & 7, that covers Rudeus' adventures following Eris' departure.

Answer (score -1):

Mushoku Tensei manga is an utter disgrace to the novel.
I'd recommend reading the translated web novel.
There's not much difference between the web and light novel. But the light novel's only been published till volume 8 right now.